# Get shuffled, non-repeated items across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, random, shuffle

I have five different pages. Each has a button that redirects to one of the others, randomly.

I am trying to make it so that the user doesn't get to repeated pages (at least not after going through them all).

I can add a function to go through random, non-repeating stuff in the same page, but how can I make that function work across different pages, remembering which pages were already visited?

I tried saving that function in an external js file and call it in the head section of every page, but it does not work.

I also tried to use localStorage, but with no results.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible, to begin with?

This is what I am working with:

```js
localStorage.getItem("currentRemainingPages");

var page1 = "0001.html"
var page2 = "0002.html"
var page3 = "0003.html"
var page4 = "0004.html"
var page5 = "0005.html"

const originalPages = [page1, page2, page3, page4, page5];
let remainingPages = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingPages.length === 0) remainingPages = originalPages.slice();
  localStorage.setItem("currentRemainingPages", remainingPages);
  const {
    length
  } = remainingPages;
  const [page] = remainingPages.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);

  window.location.href = page;
}
```

```html
<h1>Page 0</h1>
<p><button onclick="randomize()" type="button">Random Page</button></p>
```

Comment: Put the `localStorage.setItem("currentRemainingPages", remainingPages);` **after** you select (and remove) the random page from the `remainingPages`??

Comment: Notice also that `localStorage` stores strings. You will need to `JSON.stringify` and  `JSON.parse` your array (or string `.split(",")` and `.join(",")` it).

Comment: @Bergi I tried the first thing. I still get no results. As for using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, I am still learning JavaScript... I didn't get to JSON yet. What exactly would I have to do to my code, for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

- You just call `localStorage.getItem("currentRemainingPages");` but don't do anything with the result. Instead you always initialise the `let remainingPages` with an empty array
- You will need to serialise and deserialise the array, as `localStorage` only stores strings. You can simply join and split by a delimiter, or use JSON, or some other custom encoding.
- You call `localStorage.setItem("currentRemainingPages", remainingPages);` *before* you  you select (and remove) the random page from the `remainingPages`.

Instead use

```
const originalPages = ["0001.html", "0002.html", "0003.html", "0004.html", "0005.html"]
let remainingPages = (() => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentRemainingPages"));
    } catch(e) {
        return null;
    }
})();
if (!Array.isArray(remainingPages) || remainingPages.length == 0)
    remainingPages = originalPages.slice();

function randomize() {
    const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingPages.length);
    const [page] = remainingPages.splice(i, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("currentRemainingPages", JSON.stringify(remainingPages));
    window.location.href = page;
}
```

Comment: I replaced my original script with yours, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. It doesn't redirect to any page at all...

Comment: @MikeMichaels Are you getting any errors in the browser devtools?

Comment: Yes, I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at 0001.html:15" and "Uncaught TypeError: remainingPages.splice is not a function or its return value is not iterable at randomize (000.html:21) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (0001.html:7)".

Comment: @MikeMichaels OK, adapted so that it can deal with invalid values in the local storage

Comment: @That fixes the button not working. But tnow I am getting repeated pages, which I do not want. On my first try, I got through these pages: 2-4-3-4-5... And this time I am not getting any errors in the browser devtools.

Comment: @MikeMichaels Did you try to use a debugger to look at the value of `remainingPages`, does it have the values that you would expect?

Comment: @How do I do that? I'm quite new to JavaScript and programming in general. I have a basic knowledge of how to use the developer tools to look for errors. But how can I look through the value of `remainingPages`?

Comment: Either a) Under the application panel, look at Storage -> Local Storage b) it's a global variable, so just enter it in the console to access its value c) change your code to include `console.log(remainingPages)` or d) [set a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) on that line and inspect the value

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I learnt a lot from this post. I looked through the values of the `remainingPages`. Everything was working fine. I found out I was testing it the wrong way. I should have cleared the storage before testing anything.The repeated pages I was getting were actually pages from the previous session.